# Matlab graph plotting - Legend and curves with labels

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How to plot a figure like the one given below?

Here the legend (green/blue) is plotted with some values (0.10 to 0.40) on each curve. Is there any possible solution or hints to do this?

Figure Reference:

[image]

Comment: Anyone can find the reference/sample image from this link also http://postimg.org/image/qgaibu0jl/

Comment: What's your specific difficulty? At least show us that you've got the basics started

Comment: Perhaps read up "plot" in Matlab help. Pretty much has all the info you need. Also, a quick Google of plot options in Matlab will yield some helpful tips.

Comment: I know that matlab "Plot" option is helpful. @Dan I was trying to make a similar plot in matlab. Plot(x,y,'-g');legend('a','b') this type of coding is not going to provide me the accurate outcome. Eg: I want to get the green color curves. In the figure mentioned above you can see 0.10,0.15,0.40,0.20 etc are mentioned in the curves and due to that we don't require to use legends to identify graphs. So how to plot in this way..

Comment: There is no function I am aware of that handles labeling individual lines. You will have to program it manually I guess.

Comment: Just read `plot` and `spline` that maybe can help you. Provide more information and try to search more.

Comment: @ibrahimkbd you must split this into smaller questions, it's too broad. If you want to know how to label lines then only ask that. If you want to know how to plot a bunch of blue lines and a bunch of green lines then ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Plotting data labels within lines is possible with [clabel](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/clabel.html) (contour labels), although this requires that you to plot your data with the [contour](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) command.

Although if you can't plot it as a contour plot then you should be able to convert your plot data to a contour matrix format, see the matrix definition at the bottom of the help page on [the contour algorithm](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-contouring-algorithm.html). This is a simple 2 row vector defining your data points, you should be able to feed this matrix into the clabel function to print the data labels inline.

For the example below - I plotted the 3 lines using the plot command, saving the line handles in the array h. I then created a contour matrix from the plotted data, so for example if the red line had 50 data points then

```
C(1,1)=0.44; % data value to plot on the line
C(2,1)=50; % number of data points
C(1,2:51)=line1x; % x data points for the red line
C(2,2:51)=line1y; % y data points for the red line
```

I did it manually to test the idea but I'm sure you could write a simple function to create this matrix automatically from your data if required. Anyway repeat adding the other line data to the contour matrix then use the contour label command

```
clabel(C,h)
```

Which gives me this plot

[image: plot with inline data values]

Comment: Will you please provide me your details coding. I am getting an error like          "Error using contour (line 81)
Z must be size 2x2 or greater."

Comment: There is no coding really - I haven't used the contour function. I just used plot to generate the 3 lines and then built a contour matrix from the data, I linked to the format in my answer. I then used clabel to insert the values into the plotted curves.

Comment: nice one! If you could post the code that generated this figure, it would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: There is no special coding I just used the builtin function clabel. Look at the link posted for the contour algorithm this shows the contour matrix you need to create - I've added a short example to the answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :
[Example of plotLabel.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGVOK.png)

```
function h=plotLabel(x,y,varargin)
%  h=plotLabel(x,y,varargin)
% Plot like plot but on wich each line is labelled with an integer corresponding to the number of the curve in y
% PlotLabel uses the function ''contour'' internally.
%
% x: [optional] like plot, x is a vector or a matrix, if not present y curves are along dimension 2.
% y: matrix containing y value to plot, y must be adapted to x
% varargin : plot argument passed to the plotter
%
% h is the ''contour'' structure of the plot
%
% Limitation : after this plot Legend is not warking because the plot is ''contour plot'' : all curves is ONE object
%
% see also contour
%
% Matthieu RICHARD
% 2022


if nargin == 0 % Helper

    figure(14)
    subplot(311)
    x = 1:10;
    y = [x.^2 ; x+3];
    %     plot(x,y)
    h=plotLabel(x,y);

    subplot(312)
    plotLabel(x',y','r--', 'LabelSpacing' ,  200); % works also, the oritentation of x defines the way to plot Y

    subplot(313)
    h = plotLabel(y'); % to be ''compatible with plot'' if only x is given then curves are plotted along the dimension 1
    h.LineWidth = 3; % second way to change the plot characteristics
    h.LabelSpacing = 300;

else
    if nargin == 1
        y=x';
        x=(1:size(y,2));
    end

    if isvector(x) && ~isvector(y)
        if size(x,1)>size(x,2) % x est vertical
            assert(size(x,1)==size(y,1))
            x=x'; % on organise les 2 scénario de la meme facon
            y=y';
        else
            assert(size(x,2)==size(y,2))
        end
        x=repmat(x,[size(y,1) , 1]); % on adapte X avec y en dupliquant x
    end
    nbCurves = size(y,1);
    nbPts = size(y,2);
    x=cat(1,x(1,:),x); % on duplique la première ligne
    y=cat(1,y(1,:),y); % on duplique la première ligne
    z = ones(nbCurves+1,nbPts) .* (0:nbCurves)'; % levels will be the ''labels'' Curve 1 --> 1 ...
    levels = 0:nbCurves;
    [~ , h ] = contour(x,y,z, levels , varargin{1:end}, 'ShowText','on');

end


if nargout == 0
    h=[];
end
```