# Plotting data labels within lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, label, contour

My question is similar to the post: [matlab curve with label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319455/matlab-graph-plotting-legend-and-curves-with-labels)

I have some data (acquired using a function too long to show here), which gives me 2 arrays: Nv4 (337x1) and t (337x1) and I want to plot 'a=40' ***on*** the plot line. 
I should be able to use contour label, but I need to convert my data as matrix format first. The post above gives a link to explain how to convert our data, unfortunately the link has expired and I have no idea how I should convert my data to. An example would be useful !

I'm posting this as a new question because I don't have enough reputation to post a comment

Comment: Could you provide a minimal sample of your data please? Also, what is their format if not within a matrix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess there is another way, simply with `text`. Here is a sample:

```
% Create a sample curve
x = 1:337;
y = sqrt(x);
plot(x,y);

% Define position to display the text
i = round(numel(x)/2);

% Get the local slope
d = (y(i+1)-y(i))/(x(i+1)-x(i));
X = diff(get(gca, 'xlim'));
Y = diff(get(gca, 'ylim'));
p = pbaspect;
a = atan(d*p(2)*X/p(1)/Y)*180/pi;

% Display the text
text(x(i), y(i), 'a=40', 'BackgroundColor', 'w', 'rotation', a);
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Best,

Comment: Thank you, I used your trick ! However it's not working with the right rotation so I had to change it by hand and I generated the code (file->generate code) to get the exact position so that I don't have to do it by hand next time. I still would like to learn how to do it with Clabel if anyone know how to do it, but this technique suits me for now ! Thanks !

Comment: The rotation setting might indeed fail if your data are noisy. Maybe you can try to `smooth` your data prior to differentiate to get the proper angle.

Comment: Yes ! I used smooth (which I did not now about!) on my x and y data and the rotation fits my curve now ! Excellent !