# Matlab Plot Legend Locating on Each Curve

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab plot that contains relatively high amount of different data and hence if i use standard legend representation, i could not figure out which legend color belongs to which curve.

So, is there any way to put legends on each curve? Lets say "BUS7" text should be located on the purple curve (undermost one).

Thanks.

[image]

I am trying to do something like this:

[image]

Comment: like this code : see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74109284/20271573)

Answer (score 0):

The `text(x, y, txt)` function allows you to add text at a given location on the plot. [link](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html).

Looking at your example, it seems that you want to have all the labels on the left-hand side. So, one way to do it would be like this, where I have generated my own dummy data:

```
leg = {'First Curve', 'Second Curve', 'Third Curve'};

figure;
x = linspace(1,10,100);
for ii = 1:3
    y = x + ii*10;
    plot(x, y);
    hold on
    text(x(1), y(1)+2.5, leg{ii});
end
```

Regretfully, this does not do anything clever with where the label is placed - it is merely placed slightly above the first point of the curve. You can clearly easily move it along the curve, but if you have many curves, like in your case, the labels will likely overlap and you will need to tinker a bit to avoid this.

[image]